# Nifi EvaluateJsonPath by comparing with an Attribute

Tags: json, apache-nifi

What value should I put in EvaluateJsonPath
[image]

So I can get "Sayings of the Century" in this JSON

```json
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know

> $..book[?(@.author=="Nigel Rees")].title

will return "Sayings of the Century"
but
I need something like

> $..book[?(@.author=="${author}")].title

wherein attribute

> $author = "Nigel Rees"

**$..book[?(@.author=="${author}")].title** does NOT work, and I already tried different variations.
 Do I have the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put Expression Language in this field that's why your query fails. Nifi is evaluating the query without replacing the content of the ${author} EL syntax.[Expression Language not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9koqo.png)

One way to counter this in your case would be to split the JSON at the Array level (using SplitJSON) and then to route only on the array element that match the following RegExp (using RouteOnContent) : `"author" *: *"${author}"`, and discards every other array element that do not match the RegExp.